# Android Xamarin app - how to maintain form state when device screen is turned off then back on?

Tags: android, xamarin, state

I have a background in .NET web application development and have recently started working with Android development.

I have found questions related to maintaining "activity" state when the application is terminated and then reopened. But I have users who are filling out a form on a page and for some reason occasionally turn their device screens off in the middle of filling out the form. When they turn their screens back on, the data entered is all gone and they have to retype everything. Where do I need to look in order to find out how to maintain form state when this occurs?

My target Android version is 8.1 (API Level 27 - Oreo) and I am using Xamarin. I don't even quite know where to start looking for this information.

---

Edit - I'm going to add the code from my MainActivity.cs file. I have changed some non-essential stuff to maintain anonymity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using System.Linq;

namespace Namespace.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Label", 
        Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", 
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
        MainLauncher = true,
        WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.UiMode,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity :         global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity Instance;

        public bool ArePermissionsGranted = false;
        public bool IsWaitingForPermission = true;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Init(this);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            Instance = this;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental",     "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental",     "FastRenderers_Experimental");
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,     string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[]     grantResults)
        {
            if (grantResults.Any(result => result == Permission.Denied))
            {
                ArePermissionsGranted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ArePermissionsGranted = true;
            }

            IsWaitingForPermission = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you set up your Activity? How are you responding to configuration changes?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Will it answer your question if I add the contents of my MainActivity.cs file to the original post?

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OnSaveInstanceState` method to store the data in your form.Then fill it when you turn the screen back on.You could refer to [Preserve Instance State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/saving-state#adding-code-to-preserve-instance-state).

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
{
   outState.PutInt (xxx, xx);//save the data
   Log.Debug(GetType().FullName, "Activity A - Saving instance state");

   // always call the base implementation!
   base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);    
}
```

then pass this Bundle back into our `OnCreate` method.

**Or** you could try to set the `ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden|Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize` to your activity attribute.

overwrite in your activity.It will not go through the Activity lifecycle again:

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
   {
      base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }
```